# How to add in a dictionary the values that have similar keys?

Tags: python

I would like to add together the values from a dictionary in Python, if their keys begin with the same letter..

For example, if I have this dictionary: `{'apples': 3, 'oranges': 5, 'grapes': 4, 'apricots': 2, 'grapefruit': 9}`

The result would be: `{'A': 5,'G': 13, 'O': 5}`

I only got this far and I'm stuck:

```
for k in dic.keys():
  if k.startswith('A'):
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the first character of each key, call `.upper()` on that and sum your values by that uppercased letter. The following loop

```
out = {}
for key, value in original.iteritems():
    out[key[0].upper()] = out.get(key[0].upper(), 0) + value
```

should do it.

You can also use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify that a little:

```
from collections import defaultdict:

out = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in original.iteritems():
    out[key[0].upper()] += value
```

or you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

key = lambda i: i[0][0].upper()
out = {key: sum(v for k, v in group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(original.items(), key=key), key=key)}
```

Comment: Why using key[0] and not key.startswith() ?

Comment: @Paco: Because `key.startswith()` is a *test*, not a method to get the first character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_d = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    new_d[k[0].upper()] += v

print new_d
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 5, 'O': 5, 'G': 13})
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this. Here's a variant using `Counter` that nobody else has suggested and unlike Ashwini's solution it doesn't create potentially long intermediate strings:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dic = {'apples': 3, 'oranges': 5, 'grapes': 4, 'apricots': 2, 'grapefruit': 9}
>>> sum((Counter({k[0].upper():dic[k]}) for k in dic), Counter())
Counter({'G': 13, 'A': 5, 'O': 5})
```